# When i switched from ubuntu to Lubuntu i lost the external monitor. Laptop display is physically damaged

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

On 1/25/2016 I switched from Ubuntu 14.04 03 LTS to Lubuntu on a laptop (Sony VGN-NR120E) that I can only use with an external monitor because the LCD is physically damaged. The external monitor worked fine with Ubuntu. (I read on AskUbuntu that the external monitor is not displayed by default with Lubuntu.) After finding that Fn+F7 does not turn on the external monitor as shown on the key board, I discovered I can get the external monitor to display using CTRL+F7. However, When I try to log in with my username and password the external monitor shuts off and it does not appear to have logged in succesfully when I use CTRL+F7 to try again.     -Thanks.

Comment: When you say it "does not appear", do you mean that it takes you back to the lightdm login screen?

Comment: The external monitor doesn't turn on when Lubuntu boots up. If I use CTRL+F7 I can get the external monitor to turn on and see the login screen.

Comment: It is unlikely Ubuntu (lubuntu) damaged your hardware.

Comment: No. A 500lb guy stepped on the laptop. Hence the need to use an external monitor.

Comment: I found your answer! http://superuser.com/questions/640038/how-to-enable-auto-screen-update-on-monitor-plug-in-out-on-lubuntu-and-how-is-i

Comment: I read that Answer prior to posting.  However, my problem is deeper in that I can't log in except as a guest and therefore cannot save my settings. When I try to log in, the external screen disappears and when I [CTRL+F7] to get the external monitor back up it always takes me back to the login screen. I don't think it is a password issue because when i  purposefully enter an incorrect password the screen stays on but states that the password is incorrect.

Comment: @ColonelClank  I  see, this useful. Open a terminal from the guest account and use the `su` command to switch users. For example, if your username is *colonelclank* you should run: `su colonelclank` After running the command, your username should appear at the prompt.

Comment: @ColonelClank After logging into the terminal, run: `cd` to change to your user's home directory and: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/` Then, run the following command to display your xsession errors (**note** you have to be logged in the terminal with your username as this will not work in the guest home directory): `cat .xsession-errors*` There may be some useful info here, however, the problem may already be fixed so log out and try to log back in as your user to see if the problem still persists. Please post any errors.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, login to your guest account and use the `su` command to switch users in the terminal.

For example, if your username is *colonelclank* you should run:

```
su colonelclank
```

Your username should now appear at the command prompt in the terminal. Next, run the following commands to change to your user's home directory and to fix any file permission issues that may be preventing you from logging in.

```
cd; sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/
```

Now, run the following command to display your xsession errors (**note** you have to be logged in the terminal with your username as this will not work in the guest home directory):

```
cd; cat .xsession-errors
```

There may be some useful info here, however, the problem may already be fixed so log out and try to log back in as your user to see if the problem still persists.

---

**PART TWO**

If you still need a script to listen for and to automatically connect to your external monitor when plugged in, you can run the following commands to install a script to do this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git consolekit
git clone https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug.git
cd udev-mon*
sudo cp usr/local/bin/monitor-hotplug.sh /usr/local/bin/
sudo cp etc/udev/rules.d/99-monitor-hotplug.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
sudo service udev restart
```

[Click here for more info.](https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug)

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to mchid. I can't say I fixed the problem but the problem has gone away. To close the loop (pun) I'll explain where I ended up. Prior to mchid' guidance to switch users I had installed puppy. After reinstalling Lubuntu (in order to try su) I was able to log in properly without issue. Also, the external monitor became available without any special effort/issue. Time will tell.